# How to use different Auth for different controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating a project in laravel. My problem is, Since this is a shopping cart I am using different tables for customer and admins. So if request is admin then i want to authenticate from admin table and if it is from store  i want to use customer table for authentication. Is is it possible to set auth table for controllers or is it possible to use create multiple authenticator other than the default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multi Auth is a common problem that one can face in Laravel so yes it possible to create it.

You can write your own code for this or use some package for this specific functionality. They are available on github easily. [Example link](https://github.com/imrealashu/laravel-multiauth).

There is a very good tutorial for this [here](http://imrealashu.in/code/laravel/multi-auth-with-laravel-5-2-2/) which I will use for explanation.

You will need to create two tables, customers and admin. The default user table can be used for customers (or other way too). The make:auth command will create all the routes, controllers and views for the users table auth.

For admin auth, first create an admin table. Next controllers

```
app/Http/Controllers/AdminAuth/AuthController
app/Http/Controllers/AdminAuth/PasswordController
```

Edit config/auth.php file and do same for admin as given for user, using admin model when required instead of user.

```
//Authenticating guards
'guards' => [
    'user' =>[
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'user',
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admin',
    ],
],  

//User Providers
'providers' => [
    'user' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ]
],  

//Resetting Password  
'passwords' => [
    'clients' => [
        'provider' => 'client',
        'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'provider' => 'admin',
        'email' => 'admin.auth.emails.password',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
],
```

Edit route file

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    //Login Routes...
    Route::get('/admin/login','AdminAuth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
    Route::post('/admin/login','AdminAuth\AuthController@login');
    Route::get('/admin/logout','AdminAuth\AuthController@logout');

    // Registration Routes...
    Route::get('admin/register', 'AdminAuth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
    Route::post('admin/register', 'AdminAuth\AuthController@register');

    Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index');

});
```

Edit AdminAuth\AuthController.php file and add functions

```
protected $redirectTo = '/admin';
protected $guard = 'admin';
public function showLoginForm()
{
    if (view()->exists('auth.authenticate')) {
        return view('auth.authenticate');
    }

    return view('admin.auth.login');
}
public function showRegistrationForm()
{
    return view('admin.auth.register');
}
```

Create middleware for admin

```
class RedirectIfNotAdmin
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @param  string|null  $guard
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = 'admin')
{
    if (!Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/');
    }

    return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Register middleware in kernel

```
 protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfNotAdmin::class,
];
```

Use this middleware in admin controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('admin');
   }
public function index(){
        return view('admin.dashboard');
    }
}
```

Now you can use it like

```
Auth::guard('admin')->user()
```

but not directly like

```
Auth::user()
```

because we have two auths

Comment: Now it is working fine. i can see that the www.example.com/admin/register is used to create Admins and i can see a entry in routes. but for www.example.com/register user registration is happening. but there is no post method is there for register. i guess the register action is done from AuthController but i want to know from where the create function of AuthController is called.

Comment: Also please tell me how to use the adminAuth to some other controllers too. only this is enogh?                                                                     public function __construct(){
  $this->middleware('admin');
 }

Answer (score 1):

You Should use [ENTRUST (Laravel 5 Package)](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust)

But before you need to organize your database structure. 
For all type of user use your users table, have a separate customer table with foreign key user_id. Assign roles to users , When a user logged in check its role and redirect to their dashboard as per assigned role.